Problem with Building Virgo Tomcat Server locally
Trying to build the project locally - https://github.com/eclipse-virgo/virgo-root
Getting following errors
Could not resolve org.eclipse.virgo.mirrored:org.eclipse.osgi:3.9.1.v20140110-1610.
Could not resolve org.eclipse.virgo.mirrored:org.eclipse.equinox.region:1.1.101.v20130722-1314
Looks like it's trying to get Gemini and Tomcat bundles from the site
https://build.eclipse.org/rt/virgo/ivy/bundles/release/
which doesn't seem to be available now.
Does anyone know if they have moved those dependencies elsewhere ?
